# Sidekiq not running at startup of passenger server in Rails 4.1.6 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, background-process, sidekiq

I need Sidekiq to run once I start the server on our staging application. We moved to a different server instance on Rackspace to better mirror our production conditions.

The application is started with

```
passenger start --nginx-config-template nginx.conf.erb --address 127.0.0.1 -p 3002 --daemonize
```

The sidekiq files are as follows:

```
# /etc/init/sidekiq.conf - Sidekiq config
# This example config should work with Ubuntu 12.04+. It
# allows you to manage multiple Sidekiq instances with
# Upstart, Ubuntu's native service management tool.
#
# See workers.conf for how to manage all Sidekiq instances at once.
#
# Save this config as /etc/init/sidekiq.conf then mange sidekiq with:
# sudo start sidekiq index=0
# sudo stop sidekiq index=0
# sudo status sidekiq index=0
#
# or use the service command:
# sudo service sidekiq {start,stop,restart,status}
#
description "Sidekiq Background Worker"
# no "start on", we don't want to automatically start
stop on (stopping workers or runlevel [06])
# change to match your deployment user
setuid root
setgid root
respawn
respawn limit 3 30
# TERM is sent by sidekiqctl when stopping sidekiq. Without declaring these as normal exit codes, it just respawns.
normal exit 0 TERM
instance $index
script
# this script runs in /bin/sh by default
# respawn as bash so we can source in rbenv
exec /bin/bash <<EOT
# use syslog for logging
exec &> /dev/kmsg
# pull in system rbenv
export HOME=/root
source /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh
cd /srv/monolith
exec bin/sidekiq -i ${index} -e staging
EOT
end script
```

and workers.conf

```
# /etc/init/workers.conf - manage a set of Sidekiqs
# This example config should work with Ubuntu 12.04+. It
# allows you to manage multiple Sidekiq instances with
# Upstart, Ubuntu's native service management tool.
#
# See sidekiq.conf for how to manage a single Sidekiq instance.
#
# Use "stop workers" to stop all Sidekiq instances.
# Use "start workers" to start all instances.
# Use "restart workers" to restart all instances.
# Crazy, right?
#
description "manages the set of sidekiq processes"
# This starts upon bootup and stops on shutdown
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]
# Set this to the number of Sidekiq processes you want
# to run on this machine
env NUM_WORKERS=2
pre-start script
for i in `seq 0 $((${NUM_WORKERS} - 1))`
do
start sidekiq index=$i
done
end script
```

When I go into the server and try `service sidekiq start index=0` or `service sidekiq status index=0`, it can't find the service, but if I run `bundle exec sidekiq -e staging`, sidekiq starts up and runs through the job queue without problem. Unfortunately, as soon as I close the ssh session, sidekiq finds a way to kill itself.

How can I ensure sidekiq runs when I start the server and that it will restart itself if something goes wrong as mentioned in the use of upstart to run sidekiq?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run Sidekiq as a service you should put script called "sidekiq" in

> /etc/init.d

, not /etc/init